# Database creation on BlackBerry 10

Tags: c++, qt, qml, blackberry-10

I am developing an app for Blackberry devices. This app contains a database. As the API are provided on the last API version, I decided to use SQLite.

I followed every sample I could find everywhere but whatever happens,I cannot see the database.
From where i could retrieve the data.

I should add that I am currently working on the simulator.

If anybody have any idea how to store receiving message in messaging app then please help me out.

Comment: Have you tried using the TargetFileSystemNavigator to look at your applications sandbox? Some code, or even the path names you used to access your database would help.

Comment: @Nikkii: please paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

I also found this very tricky, and remember it took a long while to work out. Eventually in desperation I wrote this handy function:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QDir>
#include <QList>
#include <QUrl>

#include <sstream>

using namespace bb::data;
using namespace std;

void listContents(QDir &src, int depth=0) {
    // You app's dirs can be symlinked into libraries, so the depth can go very deep.
    // We limit it.
    if (3<depth) return;
    QListIterator<QFileInfo> entries(src.entryInfoList());
    std::stringstream spaces;

    // If you want to indent files by depth
//  for (int i=0; i<depth; i++) {
//      spaces << ' ';
//  }

    while (entries.hasNext()) {
        QFileInfo entry = entries.next();
        QString canpath = entry.canonicalFilePath();
        QString relpath = src.relativeFilePath(entry.fileName());
        if ((relpath == ".") || (relpath=="..")) {
            continue;
        }
        if (entry.isDir()) {
            QDir subdir(canpath);
            if (!(subdir==src)) {
                listContents(subdir, depth+1);
            }
        } else {
                qDebug() << spaces.str().c_str() << canpath.toUtf8().data();
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you must first strip the `/data` directory from your `QDir::homePath()`:

```
QString appFolder(QDir::homePath());
qDebug() << "appFolder = " << appFolder;
appFolder.chop(4);

QDir listSource = appFolder + "app/native";
listContents(listSource);
```

Thereafter, just check the logs to find the proper path to your database file.

Note though that, if you want to write to the database, you should copy it from the `app/native` directory to the `data` directory.

Comment: Umm... more specifically? What is it doing / saying on the debug console?